# Parallels Plesk: Add domain alias to a sub domain 11 from panel (not through SSH)

Tags: apache, cpanel, plesk, parallels

I would like to add a domain alias to a sub domain in parallels plesk 11.5.

For example i want to add something like:

```
sub2.domain2.com as alias to my sub domain: sub.domain.com
```

I am able to do it from /var/www/vhost/sites.adomain.com/conf/vhost.conf

But i want to do this from parallels panel.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no explicit way to create alias for sub domain in Plesk 11.0.9.

But you can create new **domain** sub.domain.com and create alias for this domain.

And yes, for this you should to backup your data of sub-domain, rename it(to avoid name conflict) and create a "new" domain with same name and place your data to folder of new domain.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution, tested and working (in Plesk Onyx 17.5.3) when setting up a WordPress Multisite installation:

Create a "new" domain in Plesk, and set its directory as the document root for the subdomain you want to alias.  If you have successive aliases you wish to use for that domain (e.g. additional WP Multisite domains), you can alias them off of the initial alias.